# SharedPreference chamando uma activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Se eu quiser por um sharedpreference em um botão, no caso para selecionar a cidade desejada em uma list view, como seria? Pois só encontro sharedpreference com login etc.

Comment: [Aqui](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/) tem um tutorial completo de como fazer isso.

Comment: Voce gostaria de ter uma lista para popular uma ListView certo? e Esta Lista será fixa, o Usuário não poderá trocar o nome da cidade certo? Apenas selecionar! Se as perguntas acima forem positivas, então recomendo utilizar um <string-array>. Caso seja verdade, poste aqui que lhe passo o código para carregar! Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi a pergunta, mas SharedPreferences é utilizado como uma forma de persistência em arquivo, utilizado geralmente para guardar dados de usuário, mas pode gravar em arquivo qualquer informação utilizando ele.

Para maiores informações sobre a classe e métodos relacionados, entre em: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html